# How to customize Spring Boot Actuator endpoints

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to implement Spring Boot Actuator on a non "Boot Application", is there a way to configure a pattern to endpoints like `endpoint/health`,`endpoint/metrics`? Then I'll create a second realm in my existing Spring Security configuration, I tried the documentation but I could not find a thing about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean `management.contextPath=/endpoint` ([docs here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-management-server-context-path))?

Comment: Yes, but I think because its not a boot application, it wanst reading the properties file, so I created a bean of ManagementServerProperties and setted the path there